# How to customize error pages for all 4xx and 5xx error status for Drupal 9?

Tags: error-handling, drupal, drupal-modules

I know Drupal 9 offers custom error pages for 404 and 403, but how can I create error pages for other errors like 500, 503 - to be more precise, like all 4xx and 5xx errors?

I found this module - https://www.drupal.org/project/error_page installed and configured by adding this line of code:

```
set_error_handler(['Drupal\error_page\ErrorPageErrorHandler', 'handleError']);
set_exception_handler([
  'Drupal\error_page\ErrorPageErrorHandler',
  'handleException',
]);
// Log the UUID in the Drupal logs.
$settings['error_page']['uuid'] = TRUE;
// Your templates are located in path/to/templates, one level above the webroot.
$settings['error_page']['template_dir'] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/../path/to/templates';
```

but I didn't see any changes. Can anyone help me with this module, or is there any other way that I can customize pages for all error status?

Comment: What web server? Apache, Nginx, other?

Comment: @BaldeBinos yup, other!